# weird behavior of global bool after porting to RAD11

Tags: c++, c++builder

After porting one huge project from **BDS2006** to **RAD11** (C++ VCL win32 classic compiler) I found out that one checkbox that should be unchecked at app start is always checked...

After breakpoint/tracing I localized the problem to this function:

```
void main_caption()
    {
         if (_simple_gfx) { _GLSL=0; Main->Caption=version+" Simplified graphics."; }
    else if (_GLSL)                  Main->Caption=version+" GLSL";
    else                             Main->Caption=version;
    Main->ck_simple_gfx->Checked=_simple_gfx;   // WTF here _simple_gfx is handled as true on RAD11 even if its not (even watch list shows false)
    Main->ck_GLSL      ->Enabled=!_simple_gfx;
    Main->ck_GLSL      ->Checked=_GLSL;
    }
```

where `_simple_gfx` is simple global bool set to false (confirmed also with watchlist) used to fall back to OpenGL 1.0 on questionable gfx hardware/drivers (which is not the case now), `Main` is my main window/form and `ck_simple_gfx` is the checkbox that should not be checked (but it is checked after the assignment marked with comment `WTF`).

If I reset the `_simple_gfx=false;` like this:

```
void main_caption()
    {
         if (_simple_gfx) { _GLSL=0; Main->Caption=version+" Simplified graphics."; }
    else if (_GLSL)                  Main->Caption=version+" GLSL";
    else                             Main->Caption=version;
    _simple_gfx=false;
    Main->ck_simple_gfx->Checked=_simple_gfx;   // WTF here _simple_gfx is handled as true on RAD11 even if its not (even watch list shows false)
    Main->ck_GLSL      ->Enabled=!_simple_gfx;
    Main->ck_GLSL      ->Checked=_GLSL;
    }
```

then its unchecked as it should. What is happening? the `main_caption` is called from `Main` constructor if that matters...

I do not think its related to the VCL checkbox itself because if I do this:

```
if (_simple_gfx)
```

the stuff inside get executed while `_simple_gfx` "is" still false. There is no conflict with `_simple_gfx` identificator that I know of. If the same code (just different project file) is compiled on older IDE (BDS2006 C++ Turbo Explorer) the code works as should.

Changing the `bool _simple_gfx` to `static` and or `volatile` did not change anything.

- Does anyone know what kind of bug is this and how to workaround it?
- Did global variables behavior changed in newer versions of C++ Builders? (similar to GC compilers buggy behavior for non `volatile` global variables on MCU platforms)

Sorry I did not create MCVE as the project is really huge which is most likely the root cause of problem like this.

Comment: So if you put a break point on the // WTF line and look at the value of _simple_gfx is it true or false when you have the problem?

Comment: @RogerCigol its false in watch view and should be false but behaves as if it is true which makes no sense to me

Comment: This sounds like either a *codegen* bug or *undefined behavior*. Did you step through the code with the debugger to compare the compiler's generated machine code between the working version vs the non-working version? Did you verify that all of your other variables have been assigned properly *before* `main_caption()` is called? Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the same problem in action?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am very sceptical of doing a real MCVE as this is probably related to complexity and size of source code of the project its several megabytes of code (on older version IDEs the debugger fails). My first taught was a memory leak or something however this is executed at the apps start where nothing is running yet and codegueard is silent. If it where really a memory problem (leak or overrun/underun)  then the app would not work but most of the functionality is working (appart some minor issues which are drivers related).

Comment: @RemyLebeau  I did not step in / compare  assembly mode with the old compiler as cross comparison do you have any advice on debugger tool I can do this with? Inbuild debuger from old IDE is unreliable for such huge projects and usually fails even on breakpoint and run again ...

Comment: Are you sure the variable is initialized when `main_caption()` is called? If you are calling the function in the constructor of some form, it might not be.

Comment: Try compiling the project with the new compiler and enabling more warnings (Project options -> C++ compiler -> Advanced -> Additional options), for example `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wshadow -Wuninitialized`. This should allow you to identify undefined behavior. If you cannot compile the entire project, just compile any files that might have problems and return to the classic compiler after fixing errors.

Comment: @VLL will give it a try but right now I deal with more pressing issues so it will take some time (at least a week) till I can get to it. Will comment you on how it goes ...

Comment: @VLL ok the way of adding the warnigs you suggested does not work and throws errors however I can check/uncheck them manually in `Project options -> C++ compiler -> warnings` menu and after some trial and error I found out its on linker side it created duplicate of the bool for 2 separate obj files that are linked together (both included the same file), and even few other stuff is duplicated will have to find a way to force only single entity is created from the same source code and not multiple ones ...

Comment: hmm I am thinking of using `extern` or something for that (when static no longer works as expected). But god knows when I will have time for it again ...

Comment: @Spektre You should not use `static` here, as it specifies internal linkage. How did you define the variable if you have managed to use it in multiple translation units without `extern`? Is it in a header or an anonymous namespace? That cannot work. You should have one definition in the entire program, in a .cpp file.